# Javascript lambda scoping and code factoring

Tags: javascript, node.js, lambda, scoping, code-readability

I want to create a simple to use API into some of these functions but with out being able to bind a function into a new scope I.E the scope it belongs in! I can not figure out a way to do it other then that crazy eval nonsense or doing crazy things with this that make things much much more confusing.

Conceptually I am losing my mind because the filter paramater should be run in the context of done callback. I guess that is my issue the filter parameter is not a callback it is a parameter and should have the scope of where it is running not where it is defined.

Some one please tell me that I am just missing something silly.

Are there any languages that support binding the scope of a lambda to where it is called and not where it is defined?

```
var scrape = function(selector, filter) {
    jsdom.env({
        html: data,
        src: [ jQuery ],
        done: function(errors, window) {
            var $ = window.$;
            eval('filter=' + filter.toString());
            debugger;
            var entries = $(selector).filter(filter);
            console.log('spo');
            debugger;
        }
    });
};

scrape('p',function(index) {
    debugger;
    if(this.children.length == 3) {
        return $(this.children[0]).is('a') && 
               $(this.children[1]).is('font') && 
               $(this.children[2]).is('span');
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: There's no way to define/access local variable with arbitrary name in current scope. You can change `this` temporary via `call`/`apply` or permanently via `bind` (all those are functions' methods)

Comment: I could not even do that because jQuery is defining this in the function. Things sure would be more exciting if I could.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure what your code does, but by your description, you're searching for `$.proxy`. It binds a callback to a specific context. If you were using underscore, you would look at `_.bind`

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/

Comment: should have mentioned this is on the server. I am re-declaring the filter function using toString and eval to give it the scope I think it should have.